# How to do map operations on each subset of rows in a big Spark data frame in PySpark

Tags: pyspark, rdd, apache-spark-sql

I am using PySpark, and what I want to do is the following:

A big Spark data frame df includes all the records. I want to do parallelized computation on each subset of the records divided by 'id' column in this df. The way I currently can think of is as follows: (I will use a simple example to illustrate)

```
dicts = [
    {'id': 1,  'name': 'a',  'score':  100},
    {'id': 1,  'name': 'b',  'score':  150},
    {'id': 2,  'name': 'c',  'score':  200},
    {'id': 2,  'name': 'd',  'score':  300},
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(dicts)

from pyspark.sql.functions import (
    collect_list, 
    struct
)

# df_agg will have the following schema:   id,  a list of structs 
df_agg = df.groupBy('id').agg(
    collect_list(struct(df.columns)).alias('records')
)
```

However, when I try to do

```
 df_agg.rdd.map(my_func)
```

where "my_func" is some function which mainly doing Spark data frame computations, I met some issues, and don't know how to proceed. my_func operates on a row, where a row['records'] now saves a list of structs. How do I transform back this list of structs to a Spark DataFrame?

toDF() does not work. I tried spark.createDataFrame(list, schema) where I even type in the schema as the original DF uses, still it won't work.

I am relatively new to these PySpark operations and would appreciate your help if you can let me know what is the correct way to handle this case.

Thanks!

Comment: What is `my_func`? And what is the error?

Comment: Any function which wants to convert the "list_of_struct" in 'records' above back to a Spark data frame and continue operates on this df. A simple example would be just writing as `rdd_new = df_agg.rdd.map(lambda r: spark.createDataFrame(r.records))`, and when we do rdd_new.collect(), the following error will be there:

Comment: Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o25.__getnewargs__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getnewargs__([]) does not exist
 at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
 at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
 at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:272)
 at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
 at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
 at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: *Please*, do not post error messages or long code snippets in the comments - edit & update the post instead!

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment on the error you get when trying `df_agg.rdd.map(my_func)` (if you provide an example of `my_func` I can have a go). However, you mention that you cannot convert to a DataFrame, so here is a solution to that part:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, StructField, StructType, BooleanType, ArrayType, IntegerType

schema=StructType(
               [StructField("id", IntegerType(), True), \
                StructField("records", 
                    ArrayType(StructType([StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),\
                        StructField("name", StringType(), True),\
                        StructField("score", IntegerType(), True)])))
               ])

df_agg.rdd.toDF(schema=schema).show(2)
```